# How to find elemenst under a located element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I have a web page something like:

```
<div class='product-pod-padding'>
 <a class='header product-pod--ie-fix' href='link1'/>
 <div> SKU#1</div>
</div>
<div class='product-pod-padding'>
 <a class='header product-pod--ie-fix' href='link2'/>
 <div> SKU#2</div>
</div>
<div class='product-pod-padding'>
 <a class='header product-pod--ie-fix' href='link3'/>
 <div> SKU#3</div>
</div>
```

When I tried to loop through the products with the following code, it will give us expected outcome:

```
products=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-pod-padding']")
for index, product in enumerate(products):    
   print(product.text)


SKU#1
SKU#2
SKU#3
```

However, if I try to locate the href of each product, it will only return the first item's link:

```
products=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-pod-padding']")
for index, product in enumerate(products):
   print(index)   
   print(product.text)
   url=product.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='header product-pod--ie-fix']").get_attribute('href')
   print(url)

   SKU#1
   link1
   SKU#2
   link1
   SKU#3
   link1
```

What should I do to get the corrected links?

Comment: Can you confirm the url, is it publicly accessible?

Comment: Yes, I could confirm that. if I run script like product.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='header product-pod--ie-fix']").get_attribute('href'), it will fetch al the links

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I think you asking to **share** the URL, not to confirm it. Right?

Comment: Nevermind, you have 2 identical answers now, and your issue should be solved.

Comment: LOL that's right @Prophet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should make your code functional:

```
[...]
products=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-pod-padding']")
for index, product in enumerate(products):
   print(index)   
   print(product.text)
   url=product.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='header product-pod--ie-fix']").get_attribute('href')
   print(url)
[..]
```

The crux here is the dot in front of xpath, which means searching within the element only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a **relative** XPath in order to locate a node inside another node.
`//a[@class='header product-pod--ie-fix']` will always return a first match from the beginning of the DOM.
You need to put a dot `.` on the front of the XPath locator

```py
".//a[@class='header product-pod--ie-fix']"
```

This will retrieve you a desired element inside a parent element:

```py
url=product.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='header product-pod--ie-fix']").get_attribute('href')
```

So, your entire code could be as following:

```py
products=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-pod-padding']")
for index, product in enumerate(products):
   print(index)   
   url=product.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='header product-pod--ie-fix']").get_attribute('href')
   print(url)
```